# How to disable ng-required validation for a larger form part

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, input, disabled-control

I have a large form part, that shall be disabled in some scenarios.
I am using a `<fieldset>` tag with `ng-disabled` attribute, to enable/disable the form part.

```
 <ng-form name="myForm">
    <fieldset ng-disabled="myModel.isFieldsetDisabled">
      <input id="myTextField" type="text" ng-required="true" ng-model="myModel.myAttribute">
      ... lots of other fields
    </fieldset>
  </ng-form>
```

**The problem is**: When I disable the `<fieldset>`, the ng-form is still **invalid**, because some of the input fields are empty (but ought to be required). I expected these validations to be turned off when disabled.

How to achieve a valid ng-form without fumbling with all ng-required attributes on all input fields in the disabled form.

see the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/2JpSFqBqwdfgTa2wO4Ei?p=preview

Comment: So you'd like the input ng-required attribute to be set to false when the fieldset is disabled right?

Comment: Only way I can think of is setting the ng-required attribute to use the reversed flag of your ng-disabled like so `ng-required="!myModel.isFieldsetDisabled"`

Comment: I would expect that angular skips validation for disabled fields..?

Comment: @fbid I have a quite a lot of input and select fields within the disabled fieldset. So a solution that needs adaptation to every field would not be the first choice.

Comment: @KieranDotCo see comment above

Comment: @devqon Me too :) but the reality is not with us :(

Answer (score 3):

I would try with something like this:

```
ng-required="!myModel.isFieldsetDisabled"
```

i.e.: input is required if `myModel.isFieldsetDisabled` variable is false...

Comment: The point is, that i have a full sreen page of input and select widgets inside the ´<fieldset>´. (see '... lots of other fields' in the question).If anyone finds a solution without touching each and every input field

Comment: I think a solution without adding a ng-required attribute to every input field does not exist, sorry...